# Compiling Qt 4.8.3 on Ubuntu 12 failing

Tags: qt, ubuntu, build

I am new to Ubuntu and i am getting a message while building Qt 4.8.3 on Ubuntu 12:

> Basic XLib functionality test failed!  You might need to modify the
>   include and library search paths by editing  QMAKE_INCDIR_X11 and
>   QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11 in
>   /home/majidmax/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.3/mkspecs/linux-g++.

what the proper steps to build Qt on Ubuntu?

Comment: it is Ubuntu 12.04, but is there any difference?

Comment: Have you got all these packages installed: `libfontconfig1-dev`, `libfreetype6-dev`, `libx11-dev`, `libxcursor-dev`, `libxext-dev`, `libxfixes-dev`, `libxft-dev`, `libxi-dev`, `libxrandr-dev` and `libxrender-dev`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-x11.html

the website provide the package list which must be installed

try it~

Answer (score 7):

These are the packages you need to install and you'll be good to go.  I just had this same problem and this worked for me.  These came from the link provided by Garlic Tseng in the accepted answer.  I am just putting these here for convenience:

```
libfontconfig1-dev
libfreetype6-dev
libx11-dev
libxcursor-dev
libxext-dev
libxfixes-dev
libxft-dev
libxi-dev
libxrandr-dev
libxrender-dev
```

One (copy pastable) command to install all:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libx11-dev libxcursor-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this!  10 years later and the original web link is no longer there, but the stackoverflow answer remains.

Comment: Amazing!  Glad I took the time to put it

Answer (score 4):

What about `sudo apt-get build-dep qt4-qmake`?

Try to run that command before you compile Qt (on Debian-like distros).

Answer (score 1):

Same problem i faced in fedora20 (64-bit) for Qt-4.8.3

1)-  yum install libXext-devel

(internet connectivity should be there for checking the dependency and install all dependency).

2)- ./configure

3)- make

4)- make install

5)- Installation finish successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The error message doesn't give a lot of information as to the actual issue of XLib failing.

To get more information on the error causing it to fail you can 'make' the xlib tests:

```
$ cd <Qt_Source_Directory>/config.tests/x11/xlib/
$ make
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o xlib xlib.o    -L/usr/X11R6/lib -ltcg -lXext -lX11 -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcg
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [xlib] Error 1
```

In my case above, I was using -ltcg which was being interpreted as an explicit library to include. I was using this option as it is listed on the [qt 4.8 configure options](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/configure-options.html) as:

> Use Link Time Code Generation

When I looked at the configure options using `./configure --help` I noticed that this option isn't listed.  Removing the option from my configure line fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`what the proper steps to build Qt on Ubuntu?`

1. Check the [Qt supported Platforms](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/supported-platforms.html).
2. Check [Qt for X11 requirements](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/requirements-x11.html).

   3a. Check [steps to install Qt on X11 platforms(along with build)](http://doc.qt.digia.com/main-snapshot/install-x11.html).

   or

   3b. Check [steps to build static Qt](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Building_static_Qt_on_Linux).